# HTML5 Video IE9 Red X

Tags: html, video, internet-explorer-9

For some reason my video works on every other browser (I am only using mp4 in this example but I also use ogv and webm). What's even stranger is that some videos work and others do not.

I created a little jsfiddle to show you what the issue, hopefully you could help :)

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7Bbdb/1/)
*first one works fine, second does not

```
<video controls >
<source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/alchemycollaborative/video/inspired/Hitchcock.mp4"
type="video/mp4" />
<p>Your browser does not support HTML5.</p>
</video>
<video controls >
<source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/alchemycollaborative/video/sizzle.mp4"
type="video/mp4" />
<p>Your browser does not support HTML5.</p>
</video>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There could be several things going on here:

Note that Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions run in IE5 (Quirks) mode if no  directive is declared at the top of a page! I suggest adding ``` to the top of your page.

Make sure you haven't accidentally got your IE9 instance running in IE7/8 compatibility mode: Hit [F12] and check that the items to the right of the menu in the debugger window read "Browser Mode: IE9 Document Mode: Standards"

If the steps above don't help, try adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>` to your page's header element: This will force IE9 or above to run in IE9 compatibility mode.

> **NOTE**: Use this only while debugging - if you leave this meta tag in your live page(s), anyone visiting your site with IE10 will not be able to enjoy any new HTML5 features that IE9 doesn't support!

FWIW, the following works fine on my machines (although the second video doesn't appear to exist!):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My Site's Title</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body>
  <video controls >  
    <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/alchemycollaborative/video/inspired/Hitchcock.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <p>Your browser does not support HTML5.</p>
  </video>
  <video controls >
    <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/alchemycollaborative/video/sizzle.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <p>Your browser does not support HTML5.</p>
  </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My main issue had to do with the H.264 codec. The Hitchcock.mp4 video was the correct codec whereas sizzle.mp4 was not.

However, I am still having IE9 issues. The videos do work but not 100% of the time. It seems like when one fails they all fail. My site has about 15 videos on the page. The only video that I have never seen fail is the Hitchcock video.

Comment: I suggest that you check how your other videos have been encoded. Just because the filename says .mp4 doesn't mean the video stream inside is H.264. If one or more of your other videos is corrupt, it's entirely possible that the video decoder becomes confused or broken.